# GWT uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this) help

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-rpc

I am new to Java GWT plugins.

In our code, we are using code like below,

In test1.java

```
public class RowResults extends Composite
{

   @UiField VerticalPanel vpnlWidgets;

   public RowResults()
   {

 uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this)); 
 getRows();
   }

   private void getRows()
   {

      for(RowDetails obj: RowDetailsArray)
      {
         RowWidget row= new RowWidget(obj);
      vpnlWidgets.add(row);
      }
   }
}
```

In test2.java

```
public RowWidget(RowDetails rowObj)
{

       uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this);  
       this.Row = rowObj;
}
```

I have posted here some necessary code. In this code, if I have 10 elements in RowDetailsArray, then for each elements createAndBindUi is called. It seems somewhat slow also.

Is there any way to call uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this); function one time and use that for all the 10 elements.

Also, what will happen while calling createAndBindUi(this). Whether it convert ui.xml file to class file or some thing else.

Pls Correct me if I am wrong.,

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on how complicated your `RowWidget` is. If it has no special styling, I would suggest to use a `FlexTable` instead and just insert rows in it. It is quite optimized.

Answer (score 0):

Use This Code Format.

```
public class RowResults extends Composite{
    private static RowResultsUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(RowResultsUiBinder.class);
interface RowResultsUiBinder  extends UiBinder<Widget, RowResults> {}
    public RowResults(){
        initWidget( uiBinder.createAndBindUi( this ) );
        // put all your code here if you do not have any other constructor if you have put
        //the above line in that constructor in the begning.
}
```